# TinyMCE italic tag not showing

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Here's my "constructor"

```
tinymce.init({selector:"#article_body", valid_elements:'strong/b,italic/i,p,br', formats:{bold:{inline:'b'}, italic:{inline:'i'}}});
```

Inside TinyMCE editor I can select a piece of text and apply italic and I see the italic result, same with bold. But when I get the content to save it, the italic tag is never there.

This is how I get the content

```
tinymce.get('article_body').getContent();
```

What do I have to do to make the italic tag working in TinyMCE (v4.2.4) ??

Comment: Share rest of your code please. Preferably share a snippet or jsfiddle replicating your issue. Your question is about getting content from tinymce but you did not share anything other than constructor.

Comment: There is no other code to share, pretty straight forward, a div and just tinyMCE...

Comment: There is no code trying to get any content from tinymce in your question.

Comment: ... tinymce.get('article_body').getContent(); there you go. This is obviously a config issue.

Comment: try changing the valid elements from `italic/i` to `i`. [I dont have any issue with this jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/t4yqdLt8/) If your issue still continues try and create a snippet or fiddle.

Comment: Alright, indeed it was italic/i! Thanks for your help. You can make a real reply and I'll validate it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `italic/i` value in the `valid_elements` property. Changing it to `i/italic` solves the problem.

```
valid_elements: 'strong/b,i/italic,p,br',
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/t4yqdLt8/)